# Removing GET commands from URL using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to clean up URLs for my website which uses a GET command to dynamically load a page:

domain.com/user/?name=david

How do I use .htaccess rules to remove the ?name=david so that the URL becomes:

domain.com/user/david

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems these .HTACCESS rules aren't all supported by the Lightspeed web server I'm using.  Although it's based on APACHE, there are some differences it seems which prevent the rules from working - or at least that's what I seem to be finding when I'm reading up on why these rules aren't working.

Answer (score 0):

RewriteRule ^user/(.*)$ your_script?name=$1 [QSA,L]

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try these rules in your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^name=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^user/$ /user/%1? [R=302,NC,L]
```

Comment: I've tried this but it doesn't do anything?  I've added it to my root level .htaccess file and I have ReWriteEngine on?

Comment: @chocolatecoco: I have modified my answer above, please try it. I have tested them on my web server and it is working fine. Also make sure your web server is allowing you to have user defined .htaccess files.